# Android barcode printing with Bixolon SPP-R200II

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, bixolon-printer

I need to print a barcode in a mobile bluetooth printer brand “Bixolon” model “SPP-R200II” from an android application. Using the Bixolon SDK for Android does work for a Samsung SII but not for a Motorola moto G G2. I decided not using the SDK, instead I am sending commands to the printer based on the “unified command manual” by Bixolon. I am using these lines:

```
String codigo=”1234567894”;
int GS=29;
int k=107;
int m=5;
byte[] codigobytes=codigo.getBytes();
outputstream.write((byte)GS);
outputstream.write((byte)k);
outputstream.write((byte)m);
outputstream.write(codigobytes);
```

Based on the manual this command should print an “ITF” barcode but it does not. Connection with printer was successfully stablished; even I can print text but not barcodes with this command. 
Has anybody had better luck in printing barcodes with this method and printer? I appreciate your help and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that worked fine in my app:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String barcode="12345";
        int GS=29;
        int k=107;
        int m=73;   //73 code128
        int n=barcode.length(); //code length
        int h=104;
        int HH=72;
        int Hn=2;
        int height=70;

        // code height=80
        baos.write((byte) GS);
        baos.write((byte) h);
        baos.write((byte)height);

        //width of each bar in barcode to the minimum
          int ESC=29;
          int w=119;
          int n=2;
          baos.write((byte)ESC);
          baos.write((byte)w);
          baos.write((byte)n);

        //Print label below barcode
        baos.write((byte)GS);
        baos.write((byte)HH);
        baos.write((byte)Hn);

        //Print barcode type Code 128
        byte[] codebytes=barcode.getBytes();
        baos.write((byte)GS);
        baos.write((byte)k);
        baos.write((byte)m);
        baos.write((byte)n);
        baos.write(codebytes);
    // Paper feed
        int ESC=27;
        int d=100;
        int n=2;
        baos.write((byte)ESC);
        baos.write((byte)d);
        baos.write((byte)n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one important part while printing bar codes. It should end with NUL sign. 
Add this:

```
String NUL = new String(new byte [] {0x00});
outputstream.write(NUL.getBytes());
```